# DynamoDB Retrieve an Item using iOS mobile SDK

Tags: ios, mobile, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-dynamodb

I'm starting with AWS mobile SDK for iOS and can't get to load an item properly. I have the entity mapped fine because I can save an item to the DynamoDB table.

My problem is that I can't get the information after the load operation. I'm following [this AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html#retrieve-an-item), where it says that the result will be mapped to the object. Here's my code:

```
AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];

DDBUser *user = [DDBUser new];
user.u_id = credentialsProvider.identityId;
[[dynamoDBObjectMapper load:[DDBUser class] hashKey:user.u_id rangeKey:nil] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    if (task.error) {
        NSLog(@"The request failed. Error: [%@]", task.error);
        return nil;
    }
    if (task.exception) {
        NSLog(@"The request failed. Exception: [%@]", task.exception);
        return nil;
    }
    NSLog(@"name: %@", [(DDBUser *)task.result name]);
    NSLog(@"name: %@", [user name]);
    return nil;
}];
```

Here, the first log has the correct name but the second is null.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an expected behavior. The `task.result` contains the result, not `user`. You may want to rewrite the code snippet to something like this:

```
AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];

[[dynamoDBObjectMapper load:[DDBUser class] hashKey:credentialsProvider.identityId rangeKey:nil] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    if (task.error) {
        NSLog(@"The request failed. Error: [%@]", task.error);
        return nil;
    }
    if (task.exception) {
        NSLog(@"The request failed. Exception: [%@]", task.exception);
        return nil;
    }
    if (task.result) {
        DDBUser *user = task.result;
        NSLog(@"name: %@", [user name]);
    }
    return nil;
}];
```

Comment: Fair enough, but what does this means (taken from the docs) "The Object Mapper creates a mapping between the Book item returned from the database and the Book object on the client (here, resultBook). Thus, assuming that the Book item has a title, we could access the title at resultBook.Title." How can I do that?

Comment: The website needs to be updated. You can access title as follows: `if (task.result) { Book *resultBook = task.result; NSLog(@"title: %@", resultBook.Title); }`.

Comment: Ok, I thought so too.. the website is outdated. Thanks.